# Changing the current entry in a list in Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation

Probably very basic, sorry, but I've searched extensively without finding a solution:

```
list_2 = ReplacePart[list_1, _?EvenQ -> "Sin(value of the entry in this position in list_1)" ]
```

That is, creating `list_2`, for every second entry replace its value with the Sinus of the corresponding value in `list_1`.

So for example `{1, pi/2}` should return `{1, 1}`. What is the code I should use in "..."?

On a general note: How does one address the value of the "current position" in a list? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list1 = {1, Pi/2, Pi, 3 Pi/2, 3, 10};

list2 = ReplacePart[list1, part_?EvenQ :> foo[list1[[part]]]]
```

> {1, foo[π/2], π, foo[(3 π)/2], 3, foo[10]}

```
list3 = ReplacePart[list1, part_?EvenQ :> Sin[list1[[part]]]]
```

> {1, 1, π, -1, 3, Sin[10]}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {1, Pi/2, Pi, 3 Pi/2, 3, 10};
```

With `MapAt`:

```
MapAt[Sin, 2 ;; ;; 2] @ list
```

{1, 1, Pi, -1, 3, Sin[10]}

Or `ReplaceAt` (since V 13.1):

```
ReplaceAt[x_ :> Sin[x], 2 ;; ;; 2] @ list
```

{1, 1, Pi, -1, 3, Sin[10]}

With `ReplaceAt` one can easily impose additional conditions:

```
ReplaceAt[x_ /; x > Pi :> Sin[x], 2 ;; ;; 2] @ list
```

{1, Pi/2, Pi, -1, 3, Sin[10]}

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `Cases`:

```
list1 = {1, Pi/2, Pi, 3 Pi/2, 3, 10};
Cases[list1, p_ :> If[! OddQ[p], Sin[p], p]]

{1, 1, 0, -1, 3, Sin[10]}
```